# PHP : post using prepare, not working

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I try to store form's data into a DB. I can't figure out why this code is not working... Nothing happens.
Thank you for your help.
Here is my code :

```
<?php
// Connexion à la base de données
try
{
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
// Insertion du message à l'aide d'une requête préparée

$auteur="Henri";

$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO factures (projet, fournisseur, montant, ref, in_out, commentaires, auteur, input_date, maturity) VALUES(:projet, :fournisseur, :montant, :ref, :in_out, :commentaires, :auteur, CURDATE(), :maturity');
$req->execute(array(
                    'projet'=>$_POST['projet'], 
                    'fournisseur'=>$_POST['fournisseur'], 
                    'montant'=>$_POST['montant'], 
                    'ref'=>$_POST['ref'],
                    'in_out'=>$_POST['in_out'],
                    'commentaires'=>$_POST['commentaires'], 
                    'auteur'=>$auteur,
                    'maturity'=>$_POST['maturity']
                    ));

header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

The correct code : 
- 'projet'=>$_POST['projet'] must be ':projet'=>$_POST['projet'],
- there was a missing ) at the end of VALUES SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) your values that you place into your prepared SQL statement must exactly match the values you pass on execute().

IE:

`'projet'=>$_POST['projet'],` should be `':projet'=>$_POST['projet'],`

The reason why your code did nothing was because the value of `$_POST['projet']` was being mapped to 'projet'. Because 'project' did not appear in your SQL statement, it was not mapped in. In this case, however, you are missing a ")" in your SQL statement.

However, kudos on using PDO and not the my_sql functions.

Comment: Excellent! Try surrounding your field names with ` `

Comment: I found the mistake... There was a missing ) at the end of the VALUES SQL command... it is working now.